# How to put this little code inside a class?

Tags: ruby, self

I was playing with some Ruby (1.9.3) code, trying to understand "self" and OOP concept better:

```
public #without 'public', code works only from irb, not when you save script! (why?)
def mycap
  self.capitalize
end
x = "some text"
x.mycap
#=> "Some text"
```

How do I wrap a class around above code, and retain same/similar functionality ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I know is:

```
class String
  def mycap
    self.capitalize
  end
end

p "some text".mycap
```

or maybe:

```
x = "some text"
class << x
  def mycap
    self.capitalize
  end
end

p x.mycap
p 'some text'.mycap #=> won't work, because the method mycap is only for x.
```

I hate it that many articles contain inaccurate definitions of 'self' and how it's used. 'self' changes only 2 times during the run-time of your Ruby app:

a) When you define a class (self changes to that particular class or a module)
b) When you call a method to an external receiver (self changes to that receiver)

In the first example above, when you call mycap on "some text", self changes to "some text" (which is an instance of String). In the second example, self is x which is a reference to 'some text', which is an instance of String. Personally, I didn't have a clue about self till I've watched [these videos by Pragmatic Programmer](https://pragprog.com/screencasts/v-dtrubyom/the-ruby-object-model-and-metaprogramming) , David explains is really well. Best of luck.

Comment: You don't need `self.` in `self.capitalize`, as `self` is the default receiver.

Comment: The guy is trying to understand self, so excluding it from the example will make things even more complicated for him.

Comment: Then explain that, rather than suggest that `self.` is required there (but it is otherwise a good answer).

Comment: Where did I write that self is required?

Comment: If the reader makes the not-unreasonable assumption that you have not added unnecessary elements to your code, he/she will conclude that `self.` is required.

Comment: I understand your first example, I saw that earlier and started playing with "self" and got confused so I came here to ask this question. But what's going on in second example ? What does "class << x" mean ? What's the name of the class and what are you doing with "x" ? Appending it ? I can't google search that phrase because google omit special characters

Comment: ooops, I found what "class << x" means here under related :) ... but can you define "class Example" and make my original code work from inside of it ?

Comment: Well, not exactly, since you'll either need to do something like SomeClass.new.mycap('some text') or SomeClass.mycap('some text') which is not exactly object-oriented. If you want to do something on an object, it's better for the method to be as clost to the object as possible, as with the first example. There's a reason why in Ruby you do 'some string'.capitalize and not CapitalizeClass.new.capitalize('some string')